# Novel that took place on a colony that was hovering above a supermassive planet

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a science-fiction novel that I read in what would have been the late-90's or early-2000's. The basic plot of a novel was that the main characters were investigating a murder that took place on a colony that was hovering above a super-massive planet. A couple things that stand-out though in my memory:

- The male character was a native Australian from Earth
- They had had their heart replaced with a mechanical one
- There was a side plot involving an alien artifact that had been found
- The murder was originally found near a pendulum in a park

Also, the conclusion might help as well:

> The planet was coming out of a "winter cycle" and planet life was returning. This was being covered up since its discovery would have meant that the colony would have to leave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how I managed to remember this, but the name of the novel is "Anvil" by Nicolas Van Pallandt. From the [Goodreads description](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3199553-anvil):

> The city of Kyara is a wasteland made habitable, a grand testament to
>   the future's unlimited technology. But all is not as glorious as it
>   seems, as one women has already met a sudden, violent death. Gabriel
>   Kylie has come to this city to find out the truth about his sister's
>   untimely demise. But this is a place filled with dangerous secrets -
>   secrets that could threaten an entire planet...